# How to block selected artifacts in Nexus?

Tags: maven, nexus, artifacts

I am very new to Nexus repositories.
I am trying to configure Nexus is such a way that I can tell Nexus to not use some certain artifacts which are already in the repository.

I know I can block the artifacts by using pom.xml. But, is there any way to do it by using Nexus repository interface?

Thanks!

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then you need to remove those artefacts from the nexus repo first

Comment: I think this blog post provides a better answer: https://blog.sonatype.com/how-to-keep-vulnerable-versions-of-struts-out-of-your-nexus-repository

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Go to nexus url.
2. login
3. Go to View/Repositories -> Repositories and check which artifact you want to block
   (e.g. – Releases -> com -> test -> abc-> TestApp -> 0.0.1).
4. Go to Artifact tab onthe right hand side. Copy the Repositroy path : /com/mycompany/test/abc/TestApp/0.0.1/TestApp-0.0.1.jar
5. Go to View/Repositories -> Routing.
6. Click on Add.
7. Fill in the URL pattern, Rule type and Repository type

   URL Pattern (which is a regular expression fort he URL path): 
   ^/com/mycompany/test/abc/TestApp/0.0.1/TestApp-0.0.1.jar

   Rule Type : Blocking

   Repository group : All Repository Groups (or you can choose your desired repository group)
8. Save.
9. Add the corresposing maven dependency of the blocked artifact in the pom.xml of your project. Then do maven clean install. It should throw error as now it is not able to download the jar
   /com/wincornixdorf/test/Patrick/TestApp/0.0.1/TestApp-0.0.1.jar